# DirectFB : Installing version 1.7.0 installs libdirectfb-1.2.so.9 but not libdirectfb-1.7.so.0

Tags: c, linux, framebuffer, directfb

I recently downloaded DirectFB code version 1.7 from http://directfb.org/downloads/Core/DirectFB-1.7/DirectFB-1.7.0.tar.gz. After configuring ,compilation and installation I see the below files:

```
# ls -l /usr/lib/*directfb*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     24 Dec  4  2011 /usr/lib/libdirectfb-1.2.so.9 -> libdirectfb-1.2.so.9.0.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 545516 Dec  4  2011 /usr/lib/libdirectfb-1.2.so.9.0.1

/usr/lib/directfb-1.2-9:
total 20
```

The version of the lib installed in in-correct or rather old as such when I try to execute a sample code it states that

```
error while loading shared libraries: libdirectfb-1.7.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Linking the same to version 1.2.9 gives unexpected results?

How to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue. When you apt-get libdirectfb-dev it installs 1.2.9 at /usr but when you install DirectFB the default installation is at /usr/local.

When you configure DirectFB before install use "./configure --prefix=/usr" to install it to the /usr directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can link the libraries of directfb as -ldirectfb and give the path for linking by searching for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have already installed DirectFB-1.2.... uninstall it and again install 1.7...